# need help to install php 7.2 yum packages on aws ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, php-7.2

I haven't seen any `yum` packages for `php` 7.2 on AWS EC2 and the release has been out over a month.

I have tried `yum list | grep php7` and only able see `php70` and `php71` packages.

- Has anyone installed `php72` on AWS EC2?
- Is there another `yum` repo to connect to?
- Does AWS have a delivery scheduled?

Comment: I'm in the same boat. Hope there is an answer not too late.

Answer (score 6):

Although the `@amzn-main repo` doesn't have PHP 7.2 yet (as far as I know), you can use remi-php72. According to his [release blog](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2017/12/04/Install-PHP-7.2-on-CentOS-RHEL-or-Fedora) you can install the EPEL and Remi repositories via:

```
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
wget http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
rpm -Uvh remi-release-6.rpm
rpm -Uvh epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
```

And then enable remi-php72 using yum-config-manager:

```
yum install yum-utils
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php72
```

After that, you can simply search and install php and all the needed extensions like normal:

```
sudo yum install --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="remi,remi-php72" php php-fpm php-cli ...
```

Comment: thank you!  it didn't initially work until i split the rpm line into two individual ones.  so i editted your answer with that change.

Comment: i tried several ways to get this to work.  on aws the aws repo takes over for the standard yum install php and i was successfully using yum install php71 but now when i try to yum install php72 i get errors because scl-utils is not installed and this recipe doesn't install or enable scl.  i think you're close, but if you can get it running on aws and edit the recipe it would help a lot.  thx

Comment: Try ```sudo yum install --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=remi,remi-php72 php php-fpm php-cli...```

Comment: If you're using Amazon Linux 2 AMI, `sudo amazon-linux-extras install -y php7.2`

Comment: Error: Package: php72-runtime-1.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: scl-utils
Error: Package: environment-modules-3.2.10-0.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libtcl8.5.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: php72-runtime-1.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: /usr/sbin/semanage

Answer (score 6):

As @Typel says in a comment on the other answer - if you're using **Amazon Linux 2 AMI** then

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install -y php7.2
```

Beats installing multiple external repos and has most of th basics, including mariadb and vim (everything I need to feel happy!).

See the list: `sudo amazon-linux-extras list`